# How to automatically insert a new received email into a specific Gmail label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

On my Gmail account I have create a new label named: **Work**, now I want that when I receive a new email from some specific address (for example: `myboss@example.com`) these messages are automatically inserted into the **Work** label.

Can I do this operation? What have I to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via email filters.

1. Do a search query `from(myboss@mycompany.com)`
2. At the top, click `More`
3. From the drop-down, click `Create Filter`
4. You can fill other details from the menu drop-down. Once you're satisfied, click `Create filter with this search`
5. Choose your `Work` label on the `Apply label`, and make sure you tick the box.
6. Click `Create Filter` once you're finished

Comment: Three  important options before clicking the create filter: You can apply the filter to existing conversations; you can auto archive the incoming conversation to remove the inbox label; you can now assign it to one of the new categories (Personal, social...)